# DOM not updating after jQuery removeClass function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to assign a .hover event to divs of a certain class that are within parent divs of a certain class only. Then I want a .click event to remove a class from the parent div so that the affected child div no longer responds to the .hover event.

Instead, the class is successfully removed yet the .hover event still fires.

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/DeNRG/

I think the answer is to do with using .on() but I can't work it out :(

Any help much appreciated as always :)

HTML:

```
<div class="container unclicked">
    <div class="element">
        <p class="content">Hello World!</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.container {
    background: #444;
    padding: 20px;
}
.clicked {
    border: 5px #bbb solid;
}
.unclicked {
    border: 5px #222 solid;
}
.element {
    cursor: pointer;
    background: #f2bd2e;
    padding 20px;
}
```

jQuery:

```
$(".element").click(function() {
    $(".container").removeClass("unclicked");
    $(".container").addClass("clicked");
});

$(".unclicked .element").hover(function() {
    $(".content").css({"color":"#000"});
}, function() {
    $(".content").css({"color":"#fff"});
});
```

Comment: It is working exactly the right way. You are attaching the event at that moment, it does not change when the class is removed.

Comment: Thanks, so what is the correct way to write this in order to detach the .hover event following the .click event's .removeClass function?

Comment: The best way would be to put that into your CSS (which would change the appearance as the class changes)

Comment: True **skeryl** - however the code presented is a simple example of the problem I have come across… my actual situation demands a jQuery removal of the class and resultant detachment of jQuery .hover event.

Comment: @bigtoothmedia: Doesn't my answer address what you are trying to accomplish? I've linked to a fiddle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

And if you are hell bent on doing it in jQuery,  here you go:

You need to [unbind](http://api.jquery.com/unbind/) the event. Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/lshettyl/DeNRG/3/)

```
$(".element").click(function() {
    $(".unclicked .element").unbind("mouseenter mouseleave");
    $(".container").removeClass("unclicked");
    $(".container").addClass("clicked");
});
```

You may also do this using [jQuery on](https://api.jquery.com/on/):

```
$(".element").click(function() {
    $(".unclicked .element").off("mouseenter mouseleave");
    $(".container").removeClass("unclicked");
    $(".container").addClass("clicked");
});

$(".unclicked .element")
    .on("mouseenter", function() {
        $(".content").css({"color":"#000"});
    })
    .on("mouseleave", function() {
        $(".content").css({"color":"#fff"});
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use CSS to accomplish this:
http://jsfiddle.net/DeNRG/2/

css:

```
.unclicked .content:hover
{
    color: #000;
}
```

jquery:

```
$(".element").click(function() {
    $(".container").removeClass("unclicked");
    $(".container").addClass("clicked");
});
```

html:

```
<div class="container unclicked">
    <div class="element">
        <p class="content">Hello World!</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

as epascarello said, your JQuery is being wired up correctly and does not change as your classes change.

---

Per your comment, if you truly need to change the hover behavior in jQuery, try to remove the event handler dynamically by unbinding it (as mentioned by LShetty).

Comment: Thanks - but as I have commented above, the code presented is a simple example of the problem I have come across… my actual situation demands a jQuery removal of the class and resultant detachment of jQuery .hover event.

Comment: In that case, you'll have to dynamically remove the event handler somehow. Please see: http://api.jquery.com/unbind/